# Как привязать 2Dкамеру и ее разрешения к физ. объекту?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Как привязать 2Dкамеру, а точнее все ее возможные вертикальные разрешения экрана к объекту, **не являющемуся U**I, то есть не находящемуся в канвасе. Объект этот не вариант сделать UI, так как на нем по определенным координатам происходят появляются другие объекты. Появляются они просто на сцене.

Необходимо чтобы привязка осуществлялась по ширине, т.е. объект камера была всегда впритык выровнена по его бокам.

Answer (score 0):

Лично у меня это реализовано так.

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float dumping = 1.5f;
    public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(2f, 1f);
    public bool isLeft;
    private Transform player;
    private int lastX;


    void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(offset.x), offset.y);
        FindPlayer(isLeft);
    }

    public void FindPlayer(bool playerIsLeft)
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        lastX = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.x);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (player)
        {
            int currentX = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.x);


            Vector3 target;
            if (isLeft)
                target = new Vector3(player.position.x - offset.x, player.position.y + offset.y, transform.position.z);
            else
                target = new Vector3(player.position.x + offset.x - 2, player.position.y + offset.y - 1, transform.position.z);

            Vector3 currentPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, dumping * Time.deltaTime * 3);
            transform.position = currentPosition;
        }
    }
}
```